# Label the x axis correct in a histogram in R

Tags: r, histogram

I tried to name the x axis correct.

```
hist(InsectSprays$count, col='pink', xlab='Sprays', labels=levels(InsectSprays$spray), xaxt='n')
axis(1, at=unique(InsectSprays$spray), labels=levels(InsectSprays$spray))
```

But this produces

[image]

I want the letters below the bars and not on top.

Comment: Maybe `axis(1, at=1:length(unique(InsectSprays$spray)), labels=levels(InsectSprays$spray))` ?

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally think `barplot` are more suited for categorical variables. A solution in base R could be, with some rearrangement of the data:

```
d <- aggregate(InsectSprays$count, by=list(spray=InsectSprays$spray), FUN=sum)
d <- d[order(d$x, decreasing = T),]
t <- d$x
names(t) <- d$spray

barplot(t, las = 1, space = 0, col = "pink", xlab = "Sprays", ylab = "Count")
```

The output is the following:

[image]
Since you mentioned a ggplot solution would be nice:

```
library(ggplot)
library(dplyr)

InsectSprays %>% 
    group_by(spray) %>% 
    summarise(count = sum(count)) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(reorder(spray, -count),count)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "pink2") +
    xlab("Sprays")
```

The output being:
[image]

Comment: What kind of syntax is `%>%`? Never seen this before.

Comment: It's a piping/chaining operator. It is part of the library`dplyr`. You can find an introduction to the library functions [here](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html). The *chaning* section will explain what it does. Essentially, it takes what's in the left side and directs it into the first argument of the function in the right side.

Comment: @buhtz its in `magrittr`. There is other good stuff in that library too.

Answer (score 8):

You have to plot the labels at the histogram bin midpoints. If you want to remove the axis and just have lettering, the `padj` will move the letters closer to the axis which you just removed.

```
h <- hist(InsectSprays$count, plot = FALSE)

plot(h, xaxt = "n", xlab = "Insect Sprays", ylab = "Counts",
     main = "", col = "pink")
axis(1, h$mids, labels = LETTERS[1:6], tick = FALSE, padj= -1.5)
```

[image]